# Is this casting to a sub class of ImageView problematic?

Tags: java, android, casting

So I have a class:

```
public class NetworkIcon extends ImageView {

public  NetworkIcon (Context c){
    super(c);
}


}
```

then I have :

```
NitroCooledTowerRack = (NetworkIcon)(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

looks completely redundant, right? Except if I don't put a "(ImageView)" there, the Android Studio seem to take it as an warning (not error, it still builds).

So I'm asking, is this a really bad practice? Or should I just ignore it?

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: "Unexpected casting:layout tag was imageView"

Comment: Yeah, you're gonna get a `ClassCastException` then, if you run it. If you want your custom `View` in your layout, you need to use a tag that specifies its exact class: e.g., `<com.mycompany.myapp.NetworkIcon>`. You're also gonna need at least one more constructor in that class, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by "one more constructor"? Also I can just "invent" xml tags?

Comment: To allow inflation from layout XML, you need to implement a constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`, like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12351809). You're not really "inventing" it. `LayoutInflater` will read that tag name as a string, then try to instantiate the class from that, if it can. If it can't find a class that matches, then it'll throw an Exception.

Comment: Well snap. Looks like I better find a safer way instead of tiptoeing around a minefield. Well thanks a lot.

Comment: As long as you have that class in your project, it's not really a problem. Custom `View`s are extremely common.

Comment: Yea, but overriding something major like ImageView may not be. I'm now stuck with setOnTouchlistener. Apparently ImageView does not have a setOnTouchlistener method, but its superclass View does. Come to think of it, does java call super methods automatically? If ImageView does not have setOnTouchlistener, how come there was no problem when using ImageView.setOnTouchlistener???

Comment: "does java call super methods automatically?" - Basically, yeah, if a subclass hasn't overridden it. How are you stuck, exactly? You can override that method just like you would any other.

Comment: How? I can't call "super.super"...

Comment: You'd just call `super.setOnTouchListener(listener)`, if that's what you wanna do.

Comment: Hey it worked! I swear I tried that but it failed the first time around! What the??? Anyway thanks a whole bunch man... on the other hand, the "call super class method by default" thing only work when going up one level right? That's why the super super class's method isn't called?

Comment: Hmm, not really, if I'm understanding the question. For example, here, `ImageView` doesn't directly override `setOnTouchListener()`, so your `super` call ends up being `View`'s `setOnTouchListener()`, which is "up two levels".

Comment: What do you mean? I don't have to do anything and it will go "up 2 levels" ? Pretty sure that's not the case because I got an error in logcat run time. Pretty sure I need to write something specific and tell JVM which method to call.

Comment: Nope. Just the `super` method. You've got some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

The double casting is obviously redundant. And starting from build tools v26, you don't even need a single cast.

Also remember if the view with id `R.id.imageView1` is an `ImageView`, you cannot cast it to the subclass of `ImageView`

Comment: You will get a ClassCastException in the runtime if you cast an `ImageView` to its subclass. "All `NetworkIcon` are not `ImageView`."