# Custom View onTouch does not respond

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I have  on the MainActivity:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

the layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


 <View
     class ="com.example.doie.draw.DrawingView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/drawing_area"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and 
in the DrawingView class I have implemented this method

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, although `DrawingView` get initialized in its `onCreate` when the view is inflated by the main class
the touch is not recognized!
I thought possibly it is because `DrawingView extends View` class is losing focus, so I should attach a listener to the Main class but I do not like this solution,  because in all the Custom View tutorials I saw the touch is implemented in the custom view class, not on the Main, so cannot understand why I cannot paint on my Canvas.

(EDIT is not a duplicate, please see comments below)

n.b. In any case, for further reference, I attach also the small DrawingView class
if you need:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    private final Paint mPaint;
    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

        Log.d("IVO", "DrawingView: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking into that give me few minutes, thanks

Comment: That `DrawingView` class would crash if you put it in a layout. Are you sure you're looking at the right thing?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I see it now. You want lowercase-`v` `<view>` in the layout. The `class` attribute is currently being ignored. Then you'll need an additional constructor; one that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351763.

Comment: my case is different, the OP there did not override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`, I did it!

Comment: @MikeM. you made my day, now is working, and had also to change the constructor adding `AttributeSets` as parameter. If you want/like please write a post so I can upvote you and approve it, so to increase your rep and help future people that did not use minor case `view`. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) I would actually close this as a duplicate anyway, as I know it's been asked and answered here before. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Feel free to post your own answer with the fixes, if you like. +1 for having a [mcve] in your question. It's rare here in [android]. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Ops, I manually denied was a duplicate, sorry. if you like ask me again and I will select, but just please consider that the post linked `Ontouch() isn't work with custom view? ` does not mention my particular case, as I overrided the correct method `onTouchEvent`